# need free online virtual unix pc

Tags: unix, virtual-machine

I am using windows xp and I don't have rights to install any software in my PC. Now I am studying about UNIX. I want to execute commands in terminal and use UNIX virtually. Is there any site which provides me free access to practice UNIX through online ?

Comment: plz drop a comment if u have doubt in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin already suggested, I highly recommend booting from a Live CD if you're truly trying to learn how to use a Unix-based system. The feel of typing terminal commands into a web browser somewhere over the Internet is just *not the same* as actual Unix. This still avoids installing software on your computer, but gives you a much more authentic experience.

However, if for some reason that's not an option, there are several sites that allow you to create a "shell account", where you can telnet in and execute a certain subset of Unix commands.

For example, check out [Grex's free shell accounts](http://www.grex.org/shell.xhtml). Registration is free, as long as you abide by their terms of service.

Answer (score 7):

[Koding](http://koding.com) provides free VMs for development that you could use for learning unix. The site came out of private beta yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are unable to install software on your PC could you not grab one of the *nix bootable live CDs and play with that.

Alterntively you can get a free shell account here:

http://blinkenshell.org/wiki/Start